# Guitar Pro 6 wrong GTK theme Ubuntu budgie 18.04.1

Tags: themes, gtk, multiarch, cursor-theme

I'm using Ubuntu budgie 18.04.1 with the adapta theme and papirus icon set. After successfully installing Guitar Pro 6 in a 64bit OS (which was a pain), Guitar Pro looks like an alien in my system. I know that GP is a 32bit and a GTK2 application  and maybe because of that it looks out of place, however adapta has a GTK2 folder and I would like to make GP native looking . Even the cursor is the default X.org cursor, although when I take a print-screen , the [cursor in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79Xt.png) looks right